# how to use glmrob with MT methods?

Tags: r, glm, poisson

Here is my code, but I have this error ..

```
model <- glmrob(x ~ as.factor(i) + as.factor(j), 
  family = poisson(link = "log"), data = myData,method="MT")
```

error message:

```
Error in optim(start, sumaConPesos, method = "L-BFGS-B", x = x, y = y,  : non-finite value supplied by optim
```

Comment: Can you please include data and/or code that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: I just add with the data, thanks

Comment: what library are GenIns and glmrob from? They are not base-R, so this isn't reproducible

Comment: `glmrob`is from `library("robust base")`, and `GenIns` is a data from another  library `ChainLadder`

Comment: This is getting closer, but needs to be edited further to be a reproducible example. (1) What are `i` and `j` ? (2) when you call `data()` (as in `myData <- data(GenIns,package="ChainLadder")` what is returned is the *name* of the data object, not a data frame. (3) `GenIns` is a distance matrix. Did you mean `GenInsLong` (just guessing, are `i` and `j` the `accyear` and `devyear` variables?)

Comment: I can reproduce your error with `names(GenInsLong)[3] <- "claims"; robustbase::glmrob(claims~factor(accyear)+factor(devyear), family=poisson,method="MT", data=GenInsLong)` ... can you edit your question accordingly?

Comment: ok, Sorry :) this the data in form of the GLM fitting, [myData](https://github.com/nmeraihi/notebooks/blob/master/data/genInsGLM.csv)

Comment: those data appear to be identical to `GenInsLong` except that you've subtracted 1 from the indices.

Comment: If at all possible, you should [avoid giving an external (off-site) link to your data file](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306067/what-is-the-recommended-place-to-store-attachments); it's best to try to follow some of the [other suggestions for constructing reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that don't rely on off-site resources.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suspect this is an example of Andrew Gelman's [folk theorem of statistical computing](http://andrewgelman.com/2008/05/13/the_folk_theore/):

> When you have computational problems, often there’s a problem with your model

If I replicate your example 100 times I get errors every time, but *different* errors different times:

```
library(robustbase)
data("GenInsLong",package="ChainLadder")
names(GenInsLong)[3] <- "claims"
tt <-
    replicate(100,
        {cat(".")
         try(robustbase::glmrob(claims~factor(accyear)+factor(devyear),
                   family=poisson,method="MT", data=GenInsLong),
           silent=TRUE)
         })
table(tt)
```

gives 80 instances of your "non-finite value supplied by optim" error and 20 cases of "Error in solve.default(de/n):  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[x,x] = 0" for a variety of values of x.

I've dug down within the function, using `debug` on various levels.  The problem seems to be that the initialization procedure (`glmrobMT -> beta0IniCP -> betaExacto`) randomly samples (without replacement) a number of rows from the data equal to the number of columns of the model matrix (19) and tries to fit a poisson GLM to it.  Because of the structure of your data, these subsamples are almost always multicollinear, leading to `NA` values in the coefficients, which screws things up down the line.

I don't know how to fix this, but I would ask the following general modeling questions:

- are you sure it makes sense to fit a model with 19 parameters to a data set with 55 observations?  The usual *liberal* rule of thumb is N/p > 10, this is N/p approx 2 ...
- are you sure it makes sense to fit a Poisson model, even a robust one, to a response with a mean value of about 2.5 million?  The implied coefficient of variation for a Poisson model with mean 2.5 million is sqrt(V)/mean = 1/sqrt(mean) = 0.0006. Even though these are counts, they're so large that I'd suggest a model based on a continuous distribution ...

Comment: Well, when I use glmrob with the Huber Psi, I Have the expected result and every thing works great. Now, it seems that the problem is inly from the choice of the M-estimator, I think I have to investigate more and more...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, if I have some thing new I'll let you know.